# NodeJS Chat: store usernames

Tags: node.js, chat

I am building a chat with NodeJS but it won`t store the usernames in the var users:

```
// chat sockets
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3872, { log: false });
var users = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('requestUsername', function(username) {
        socket.username = escape(username.value);
        users.push({
            username: username.value
        });
        console.log(username.value + " joined the chat. "+ users.length +" chatters online now!");
        console.log(users);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    });
});
```

So, when somebody join, example: Steve, the var users is: {username: 'Steve'}, but when Simon joins: {username: 'Simon'} and Steve is now gone from the users var? Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't restart the server ?

Comment: Or cleaning the array when a user disconnects?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I got the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
// chat sockets
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3872, { log: false });
var users = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('requestUsername', function(username) {
        socket.username = escape(username.value);
        users.push(username.value);
        console.log(username.value + " joined the chat. "+ users.length +" chatters online now!");
        console.log(users);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    });
});
```

I had no idea why but this works?